# understanding CSS image overlay property

Tags: css

Kindly explain to me this code for overlay...

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #008CBA;
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete.

Comment: This is not even a question...

Answer (score 0):

From Mozilla's documentation on positioning:

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor (non-static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example
So what the following code is likely doing is setting the item being styled to fill its parent, likely the entire body or document. If I had to guess, it's a fullscreen overlay:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Its basically saying make sure the item has no space on any side.
The `width` and `height` properties are doing the same thing, making sure that it fills its parent. The `transition` property is just adding a fade in animation that takes half a second to complete, and the `background-color` property is exactly what one would expect. It sets the background color of the item being styled. The `opacity` just means that when the fade-in animation completes, the background will be semi-translucent.

But this is not a good or useful question for StackOverflow. Because all of this information can easily be found through Mozilla's CSS documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference, or with any DuckDuckGo search for CSS properties.